# Is it possible in Rails to check whether a redirect or render had already been issued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

Ruby 2.0.2, Rails 4.0.3, Sorcery 0.8.5

I tried to issue a redirect in my code, only to receive the error message that a redirect or render had already been issued.  If that is the case, I'm happy to return.  However, if the method is called for any other reason, I'd like to check to see if a redirect or render had been issued and, if not, issue it.  The code is authentication based on Sorcery.

In the application controller, I have:

```
  def not_authenticated
    redirect_to login_url # , :alert => "First log in to view this page."
  end
```

This ends up checking for current_user, as follows:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= @view.current_user unless @view.blank?
    begin
      @current_user ||= Associate.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id].blank?
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      return
    end
    current_user = @current_user
  end
```

In the rescue, I'd like to determine whether or not a redirect or render had already occurred, so that I could redirect_to login_url if not.  This would mean, of course, that it was called from a different method, which it is.  Thanks.

Comment: Is your login page calling `current_user`? If so, why?

Comment: @Substantial No, it does not.  The trace did not show any of my code other than what is here involved.  Sorcery was checking current_user.  It's a transient condition and I didn't save the trace so I don't have more than that.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can call `performed?` in your controller to check if `render` or `redirect_to` has been called already:

```
performed?               # => false
redirect_to(login_path)
performed?               # => true
```

Read more about [`performed?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-performed-3F) in the Rails docs.