# Ruby/Rails break out of nested method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `method1` which calls other methods depending on params and then returns a json. One of these methods checks if a specific user exists. If the user doesn't exist the method should render a JavaScript alert. At first I got an error that render was called multiple times (which was correct). So I tried adding `break` but received an `invalid break` error. So I tried `return` but then I still get the `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action`. How can I break out of method1 when I'm in method2, so that only the render in method2 gets called?

```
def method1
  data = case params["foobar"]
    when "case1"
      methodxy
    ...
    else 
      method2
    end
  render json: data
end

def method2
  if user.exists?
    return {...}
  else
    render(
      html: "<script>alert('Unknown user!')</script>".html_safe,
      layout: 'application'
    )
    return
  end
end
```

Comment: either way, there will be situation where you call render multiple times. So, you need to add your `render json: data` in a different condition where you don't want the json data to be rendered!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446375/is-it-possible-in-rails-to-check-whether-a-redirect-or-render-had-already-been-i

Comment: @hyphenbash so there's no way to break out of method1 without it rendering the json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Technically* you could achieve this with a `throw ... catch`, which is essentially acting like a `GOTO` statement. But I would not advise this; the code is already too messy, and you'd be making the problem worse.

Instead, you should aim to clean up the flow in `method1`. Make the logical flow and responses clearer. For example, maybe something like:

```
def method1
  if !user.exists?
     render(
      html: "<script>alert('Unknown user!')</script>".html_safe,
      layout: 'application'
    )
  else
    data = case params["foobar"]
      when "case1"
        methodxy
      ...
      else 
        method2
      end
    render json: data
  end
end

def method2
  # ...
end
```

You could then refactor this further, e.g. by moving the `user.exists?` check into a `before_filter` and moving that `case` statement into its own method, to simplify things.

The end result could look something along the lines of:

```
before_filter :ensure_user_exists, only: :method1

def method1
  render json: foobar_data
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite new to Rails and programming in general and I've never heard of `before_filter`